# How can I take a variable in a method call and use it to identify one of several objects to set in java

Tags: java, object

I have a class that creates an object, which creates and manages 9 other objects, and I'm trying to write a method which can get an int from one object and set it in another.

To do this I figured I have to identify the two objects in the method call, I tried with taking a string, but that didn't work.

```
public void moveNumber(String object1, String object2)
{
    int number = 0;
    number = object1.getNumber();
    object2.setNumber(number);
}
```

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Do you understand that your code can not work since there is no method called `getNumber` on `String` class?

Comment: yes, but I don't know how I can call the methods I need without the object name in place when I'm compiling

Comment: see my answer and my edition below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to give you an example on how it should work:

Here is a class:

```
public class MyClass {

    private int number;

    public MyClass(int number) {
        setNumber(number);
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

}
```

Here is your `moveNumber` method. I set this method `static` in order to call it from `static void main()`. If you want to call it from your code, you should not need to set it `static`.

```
public static void moveNumber(MyClass object1, MyClass object2)
{
    int number = object1.getNumber();
    object2.setNumber(number);
}
```

Here is a code to manage all this things:

```
public static void Main() {
    MyClass obj1 = new MyClass(3);
    MyClass obj2 = new MyClass(4);

    moveNumber(obj1, obj2);

    System.out.println("obj1 number ===> " + obj1.getNumber());   // prints 3
    System.out.println("obj2 number ===> " + obj2.getNumber());   // prints 3
}
```

You can see this code running here: https://ideone.com/2kpoBr

**Edit**

Maybe you do not know the class of the objects when you give them into the method. So, you'd better create an `Interface` (in my example, I would call this interface `IMyClass`):

```
public interface IMyClass {

    void setNumber(int number);

    int getNumber();

}
```

And you change `MyClass` to implements this interface:

```
public class MyClass implement IMyClass...
```

Then, in your method, you set parameters as IMyClass:

```
public static void moveNumber(IMyClass object1, IMyClass object2)
```

In this way, you'll be able to have many implementations of `IMyClass` and pass object implementing `IMyClass` without being sure of their implementation `Class`.
But, if you want to call `getNumber`, you have to be sure that this method exists on the object you manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing two objects, you have to declare the method with the object types instead of defining it with `String`, as shown below:

```
// replace Object with the type of object you wish to pass
public void moveNumber(Object object1, Object object2) 
{
    int number = 0;
    number = object1.getNumber();
    object2.setNumber(number);
}
```

Comment: `getNumber()` does not exist on `Object`.

Comment: I know that, that is why I have commented to replace Object with the type the OP wishes to pass, that is just an example

Comment: Oops, sorry. But you'd better set `#Object` instead of `Object` :).

Answer (score 0):

If object and object2 are real objects that you made, then just use them

```
public void moveNumber(ObjectType1 object1, ObjectType2 object2)
{
    object2.setNumber(object1.getNumber());
}
```

assuming you have a setNumber(int i) in object2 and getNumber() in object1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, you need not a `String` type, but create your own type like this:

```
public class MyObject() {
 private int i;

 public int getNumber() {
  return i;
 }

 public void setNumber(int i) {
  this.i = i;
 }
}
```

Then create objects:

```
MyObject object1 = new MyObject();

MyObject object2 = new MyObject();
```

And pass created objects with type `MyObject` to `public void moveNumber(MyObject object1, MyObject object2)`.